# Calling operator() syntax

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sfml

ProjectileManager inherits from EntityManager, which has this as a protected member:

```
struct EntityDeallocator{
    void operator()(std::pair<sf::String,std::shared_ptr<Entity>> p)const{
        p.second.reset();
        std::cout << "object removed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The ProjectileManager update function:

```
void ProjectileManager::update(double frameTime){
for(std::map<sf::String,std::shared_ptr<Entity>>::const_iterator it = entities.begin();it!=entities.end();it++){
    it->second->update(frameTime);
    it->second->getObject()->draw(*SfmlFramework::Singleton()->window);
    if(it->second->getObject()->getSprite()->GetPosition().x > SfmlFramework::Singleton()->window->GetWidth() || it->second->getObject()->getSprite()->GetPosition().y > SfmlFramework::Singleton()->window->GetHeight()){
        //I want to call EntityDeallocator on it
    }
}
```

}

How would I call EntityDeallocator on `it`? I have tried EntityDeallocator(it) but that says `it` is an unreferenced local variable.

Comment: Do you need to instantiate an Entity_Deallocator object before calling it?  For example, Entity_Deallocator()(it).  (Away from my C++ compiler, I am commenting only because I see no one else available to comment at the moment.  If this comment solves your problem, then you can post the answer, yourself.  If it does not solve it, disregard.  Good luck.)  Update:  I see that @SanJacinto has now answered.  I think that he is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Says what is an unreferenced local variable? Post your error strings, not your approximation of the error strings..

As for how to call a non-static member function, they are always the same. You need a member function, and an object to bind it to.

```
struct Fred
{
    operator()(){}
}

//later on...

Fred fred;
fred();
```

Although not *directly* pertinent to your question, you may find this link very helpful for understanding how C++ calls member functions. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: 'it' is an unreferenced local variable. Edited